# Unsure of rigorous use of Axiom of Union - example exercise is Tao's Analysis I 3.5.1

Tags: set-theory

I am concerned that I don't fully understand the Axiom of Union and how to use it **rigorously**.

Exercise 3.5.1(iii) from Terence Tao's Analysis I provides an opportunity to use it:

> (iii) Show that regardless of the definition of ordered pair, the
> Cartesian product $X \times Y$ of any two sets $X,Y$ is again a set.
> (Hint: first use the axiom of replacement to show that for any $x \in
> > X$, that $\{(x, y) : y ∈ Y\}$ is a set, and then apply the axiom of
> union.)

Note that we can only use the axioms already introduced up to this point in the book.

---

**My Solution**

Fix an $x' \in X$ and apply the Axiom of Replacement to Y as follows. Consider the statement $P$:

$$ P(\;y, (x'y)\;) : (x',y) \text{ is an ordered pair with } y \in Y $$

This statement $P$ is true if $(x', y)$ is an ordered pair with $y \in Y$. For every $y$ it is true for at most one ordered pair $(x', y)$, therefore it is suitable for use by the Axiom of Replacement. This gives us a new set $S$ of ordered pairs:

$$ S_{x'} = \{ (x', y) : y \in Y\} $$

Remember, $x'$ is fixed.

Now we need to iterate over $x \in X$ and we can do this using the Axiom of Union, which defines the following set:

$$T = \bigcup_{x \in X} S_x = \{ (x, y) : x \in X, y \in Y\}$$

This set $T$ contains all the combinations of $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ in the form of ordered pairs $(x,y)$.

This the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is a set. $\square$

---

**Notes**

I have tried reading two books, and also Richard E Bordchard's YouTube course, for different perspectives on the Axiom of Union - but I don't think I understand it fully.

**The focus of my concern is the use of $x \in X$ as an index for the union, $\bigcup_{x \in X}$.**

Tao's book uses a third invented set of labels to do such indexing, which seems overly complicated and unnecessary - perhaps I am missing something?

---

**Additional Note on Proof Strategy**

Intuitively we're trying to iterate over both $X$ and $Y$ to ensure all combinations of $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ are accounted for.

I can understand (I think) that we can use the Axiom of Replacement as an "inner loop", and then the Axiom of Union as an "outer loop"... but why not use the Axiom of Replacement twice, for both the inner and outer loops? That is, for each $(x', y)$ we replace each element of $x \in X$ with $(x,y)$?

Is it because this would give us a nested set, whereas the union gives us a suitably flattened set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to form the set union $\bigcup_{Z \in S}{Z}$, or in common set theory notation, $\bigcup{S} = \bigcup{ \{\, Z \mid Z \in S \,\} }$, you first need to have the set $S$ at hand.  In standard $\mathsf{ZF}$ set theory, the axiom of union is
$$\forall S \exists U \forall z ( z \in U \Longleftrightarrow \exists Z ( z \in Z \wedge Z \in S ) ).$$
This says that, given any set $S$, you can form *a* union $U$. You may think of $U$ being “constructed” in the following manner:

1. take any set $Z \in S$,
2. pour all elements from $Z$ into $U$,
3. repeat steps 1 to 2 for all other elements of $S$.

You may prove that for any set $S$, any unions $U_1$ and $U_2$ which satisfy equivalence in the union axiom must be equal via the axiom of extensionality (that sets are equal precisely when they contain the same elements).

---

In broad strokes, the proof of the exercise proceeds as follows.

- Assume that for any objects* $x$ and $y$, you have defined another object $(x, y)$ which exists uniquely. More accurately, you have some well-formed formula $P(x, y, z)$ for which you can prove $\forall x \forall y \exists! z P(x, y, z)$. It is helpful to parse $P(x, y, z)$ as “$z = (x, y)$” but whether this $z$ actually satisfies the “defining property” of an ordered pair is irrelevant for carrying out the rest of the argument. The crucial part here is that $\forall x \forall y \exists! z P(x, y, z)$.

The argument below is symmetric wrt to switching the labels of $X$ and $Y$. Although I start with $X$ as you have, you could choose to do otherwise.

- For any $x \in X$, prove that $ \{ x \} \times Y $ exists and is unique. More technically, fix $x \in X$ as a parameter. Then use an instance of the replacement axiom schema to replace every element $y \in Y$ with $ (x, y) $ via $P(x; y, z)$ which is allowed due to $\forall y \exists! z P(x; y, z)$. *Define* the set that you thus receive by $\{ x \} \times Y$, after proving it must be unique. Rigorously speaking, what you will show here is that there is a well-formed formula $\tilde{P}(Y; x, T)$, which reads “$ T = \{ x \} \times Y$”, for which $\forall x \forall Y \exists! T \tilde{P}(Y; x, T)$.
- Fix $Y$ as a parameter. Again use an axiom of replacement on $X$ with $\tilde{P}(Y; x, T)$ to replace each element $x \in X$ with $\{ x \} \times Y = S_x$. This is allowed because $\forall x \exists! T \tilde{P}(Y; x, T)$. The set that you get is $S := \{\, \{ x \} \times Y \mid x \in X \,\} = \{\, S_x \mid x \in X \,\}$.
- Use axiom of union on $S$ to get $\bigcup{S}$.

Finally, convince yourself that $ \bigcup{S} = \bigcup{\{\, \{ x \} \times Y \mid x \in X \,\}} $ is $X \times Y$.

* "Objects" $x$, $y$, and $(x, y)$ may be sets, or some other primitives (atoms) depending on the background.

---

It is not possible to skip the use of axiom of union in your alternative argument. An informal justification is as follows. Take two finite sets $M$ and $N$ with $|M| =: m > 1$ and $|N| =: n > 1$ elements. We would expect that $| M \times N | = m \cdot n > \max{\{m, n\}}$. However, using only replacement on sets $M$ or $N$ will *not* give a “bigger” set. Whatever set you would get, it would have at most $\max{\{m, n\}}$ elements.

You need to glue your sets $S_{x'}$ together which is what the operation of union allows.

Comment: Thanks Linear, I will take some time to read and understand your answer, which is at a level more advanced than I am used to. Can I ask your thoughts on my concern about the use of the axiom of union? Did I use it correctly?

Comment: @Penelope The indexed use $\bigcup_{x \in X}{S_x}$ is correct, if it's interpreted in the right way. Here, it should be taken to mean exactly that $\bigcup_{x \in X}{S_x} := \bigcup{S}$. The set $S$ needs to "already exist" before you use axiom of union. This set $S$ is obtained with the second use the replacement schema as outlined in the answer. $\bigcup_{x \in X}{S_x}$ slightly obscures that the $S_x$'s form a set which allows union; whereas $\bigcup{S}$ forces you to think where $S$ comes from. Generally, it's good to be conversant with both notations and use whichever is more convenient.

Comment: I've used the axiom of Replacement once to get $\{(x', y) : y \in Y\}$, and. then the axion of Union once to get $\{(x,y): x\in X, y \in Y\}$. ... however you suggest two uses of Replacement... so it seems I have made a fundamental error?

Comment: @Penelope In a strict sense, you have indeed skipped one step. I only point this out since you asked for a rigorous answer. It's common, and sometimes useful to gloss over such details if the current learning goal lies elsewhere. Just to clarify, there isn't anything mystical about the second use of replacement. What you've got are sets $S_{x'}$. Then you "take their union". Assumingly, you're already considering the sets $S_{x'}$ together as a collection in your mind before you take their union. The second use of replacement makes this precise: the sets form $S$ whose union is what's wanted.

Comment: Thanks Linear - I am grateful for your patience and replies. I understand that it is common to skip this ... and intuitively I think I'm happy with the proof strategy I did. However I would like to read about the "rigorous" issue you raise in this last comment - do you have any recommendations for an online article or book segment? I have searched myself with no luck - most people seem to "just use" union.

Comment: @Penelope How familiar are you with the notation of predicate calculus? Perhaps I've been explaining from the wrong angle. If you look at axiom of union given in my answer, you'll probably want to take $S := \{\, S_x \mid x \in X \, \}$. That's fine, and I'm doing the same. The question is, how do you know that the set $S$ exists? An analogy would be thus. Take any sets $A$, $B$. How do you know that $\{A, B\}$ exists? Right, via the axiom on pairing (and specification for uniqueness). To be rigorous, you may not say "it's intuitive that it exists", a reason is required. It's the same for $S$.

Comment: @Penelope The usual route taken in rigorous set theory is to define the ordered pair of sets as the Kuratowski ordered pair. Then proof of the existence of the Cartesian product of two sets may be done differently. In addition to the axioms of predicate calculus with equality, that proof does *not* use replacement, only extensionality, specification, pairing, union and power set. This common exposition is explained, for example, in Halmos's *Naive set theory*. The early chapters should help you a great deal, it's notorious for its beautiful honestly concise writing. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Linear - I have learned something today. I had not appreciated the importance of ensuring the set S exists and your answer, initially appeared too difficult, has started to make more sense with each repeated reading. Thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome.